# Let $p \in \mathbb{Z}$ so that if for all $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$ where $p \mid (ab)$ is true then $p \mid a$ or $p \mid b$. Does this makes $p$ a prime?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility

I know this is related with Euclid's Lemma (the difference is that the lemma starts by assuming that $p$ is a prime which we don't here). I got this question in an exam and couldn't prove the implication. I started by assuming $q$ was a positive divisor of $p$, but I couldn't seem to go very far.

Edit: A better and more acurate phrasing of the problem would be

Let $a,b, p \in \mathbb{Z}$ prove that if $p>1$ has the property that for any $a,b$ the implication $p|(ab)⇒p|a∧p|b$ holds true, then $p$ is a prime.

Comment: There are certain $p$ that must be excluded if the result is to be correct: $1$, $-1$, $0$.  And (depending on your definition of prime) we may have to exclude all negative $p$.

Comment: Hint: $6 = 2 \times 3$, so $6$ is not prime. $6 \mid 6$, but $6 \not\mid 2$ and $6 \not\mid 3$.

Comment: As the answer of @ÉtienneBézout indicates, your title is incorrectly stated. It should be "Let $p \in \mathbb{Z}$ so that for all $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$, if $p | (ab)$ then ..."

Comment: Does (a,b) = gcd(a,b)  if so this statement most absolutely is *not* true.

Comment: @fleablood Where did you see $(a,b)$?

Comment: (ab) .  In parenthesis... means gcd to me much sooner than it means a product-- which doesn't require parenthesis.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose that $p > 1$ and that $p$ is not prime . Then we can write $p = de$, where $d$ and $e$ are proper divisors of $p$, so that $1 < d,e < p$. Clearly $p|(de)$, so $p|d$ or $p|e$, by assumption. But then $p \leq d < p$ or $p \leq e < p$. Contradiction!

EDIT:
Just to clarify, what I assume and what you ought to be saying, is that if $p > 1$ has the property that for *any* $a,b$ the implication $p|(ab) \Rightarrow p|a \wedge p|b$ holds true, then $p$ is a prime.

As stated, you could take $p = 6$, $a=b=2$. Then the implication $p|(ab) \Rightarrow p|a \wedge p|b$ is *true* because $p|(ab)$ is false, but certainly $p$ is not a prime.

Comment: Proof by ontradiction is not necessary: if $p=ab$, then of course $p\mid ab$; so either $p\mid a$ (which implies $b=1$) or $p\mid b$ (which implies $a=1$).

Comment: @egreg Well, isn't it basically the same proof? I personally have no qualms about proof by contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely not!  This is true for all integers.  (a,b)|a and (a,b)|b so *if* p|(a,b) then p|a and p|b.